# NFC with ACR 122s and Android ICS

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am currently involved in a project in which I need to communicate using NFC but I'm stuck. The devices are a ACR122s kit and  a Galaxy Nexus ( ICS  4.0.4.). After a long search I had selected the ISMB-SNEP library  (http://code.google.com/p/ismb-snep-java/) under Windows but I cannot manage to get the sample code to recognize the ACR reader/writer. The software included in the ACR product box does recognize the reader/writer though.

Is there any way to get ISMB-SNEP library to work correctly with ACR122s?
Should I pick another (more suitable?) library?
Would you recommend me to get another NFC reader/writer?
Has anyone made any reader/writer successfully exchange information with an Android ICS phone in p2p mode?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a different reader, like the [idChamp](http://serialio.com/products/RFID/Mobile/idChamp/idChampRS2ProxBT.php), you could use [SerialMagic Gears](http://serialio.com/support/SerialMagic/Android/API_Android.php).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's reading your machine, but it will give you a message something like 
machine can not be read/not supported/ .. etc

Because of a small issue in the code, the code checks if there's a card being scanned right now. If not it will throw an exception which doesn't make sense.

Fix where the exception is being thrown and it shall work fine.